# Is there any way to install Windows apps on Android?

Tags: installation, windows

I am using HP 630 notebook running on Android OS and trying to install Windows apps (e.g. Microsoft Office suite 2007), but it denied me access since it's not an APK.

Is there any way to go by?

Comment: The [HP 630 Notebook](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=5211547) runs Windows and doesn't support Android. Is this really the device you mean?

Comment: There are emulators, but they are very poor quality. As Dan said the notebook runs Windows... What exactly are you trying to do. As a rule you can't install any software for one OS on another, unless you have an emulator. These emulators are heavy duty software and can be very slow to run.. The Android Emulator in the SDK can take a minute to boot on a normal quad core PC.

Comment: @RossC Genymotion ftw! I am biased ;) *its fast!*

Comment: OP: Android has no clue on how to run windows apps, you are misunderstanding it. Same principle as Windows cannot run Mac OSX software and vice versa, different platform architectures, same applies here in the case of Android.

Comment: Thanks so much, and how is VS-ANDROID installation is done, can you explain it a little bit for me

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any workaround to allow MS Office to be installed on an Android OS.  I would suggest trying Google Docs instead.  You get the same functionality such as a Word Processor and Spreadsheet software just like in MS Office and you can save them as MS Office file types as well.  You can create and edit Documents and Spreadsheets from your mobile Chrome browser or the Google Drive app.  The desktop version of Chrome will let you edit and create Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentation, Drawing and more.  Hopefully, this will meet your needs.  If not, there are plenty of alternatives in the Play Store that will give you MS Office-like functionality.  Some of them are pretty good and all of them are super cheap when compared to the cost of MS Office.

Comment: Thanks so much. Now have you tried android os on your laptop before?